# как заставить приложение использовать больше 1 гига памяти?

Tags: c#

решил почитать про ML.NET
взял пример из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/github-issue-classification) GitHubIssueClassification

подготовил свой набор данных, примерно 1,3 млн строк для обучения.
при обучении сети получаю ошибку Out Of Memory, хотя свободной памяти еще 30 гигов свободной есть.

заметил что приложение жрет только гиг памяти и все.

в настройках проекта поставил что приложение х64

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как заставить приложение использовать больше 1 гига памяти ?

UPD.
перенес код на .NET 4.8
ошибка та же. не хватает памяти.

Comment: В Ресурсах, наверное.

Comment: @Эникейщик в ресурсах это как ?  где ?

Comment: .NET какой используете? В какой коллекции храните?

Comment: точно 1.3 млн, а не 1.3 млрд?

Comment: @rawman вон слева самое нижнее. Что там?

Comment: @StanislavPechezerov в файле для обучения 1416711 строк, 3 поля в каждой строке. общий размер файла 100 мегабайт.

Comment: @Эникейщик там пусто

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica использую net core 2.2, так же побовал последнюю 3.1

Comment: @rawman насколько я помню 2GB лимит на память есть и в x64. Его убрали только в .NET 4.5

Answer (score 0):

Все верно. Действительно проблема с нехваткой памяти. 
Как выяснилось тренировка некоторыми методами очень ресурсозатратный процесс.

У меня получилась такая статистика при обучении методом SdcaMaximumEntropy:

1. при обучении на 540тыс строк в файле, алгоритм съел всю память, это 30 Гигов и еще 115 Гигов файла подкачки. на обучение ушло чуть больше 12 часов.
2. при обучении на 1,4 млн строк в файле, мало того что ушла вся память, так еще и он захотел файл подкачки больше 2 Тб, сколько именно неизвестно, у меня было только 2Тб и про время обучения тоже не скажу, не смог запустить обучение на этом объеме входных данных.